# Android Studio - 2 string arrays into listview

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I have 2 EditText boxes - one for title and one for description. I'm looking to convert whatever the user enters in both into Strings then store them in 2 String Arrays when the post button is clicked.

Then I want to send the two Strings that are in the Arrays current positions to a vertical ListView so that the title sits above and the description below.

The aim is to be able to keep adding posts (title + description) to the ListView.

I have been trying for over 15 hours now so any help would be much appreciated, keep in mind I'm new though!

Comment: 2 string arrays or a string array with two elements?

Comment: Use custom listView with list item of two textview (title+description) and adapt them with custom adapter from 2 arraylists of string as you want,.

Comment: Why not use ArrayList<Foo>?

Comment: You can use getter setter to save all the entered values & you can instantly add the new value to existing arraylist and show that in listview with custom adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create one Class with both strings like:**

```
Class Foo
{
 private String name;
 private String description;

   // getter setters
}
```

**Than add instance it in arraylist:**

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setName("batman");
foo.setDescription("I'm a batman!!!");

yourArraylist.add(foo);
```

now use this list :)